# Server side images generation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, serverside-javascript, image-generation

Are there any tools that allow you to generate images on the server side using JavaScript langauge? I'm investigating the possibility of using the same JS code to render images on the client side and on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this npm package - it can do anything from capchas to photo resazing on server sidde

https://npmjs.org/package/canvas

For client side... i do not know, but it works super for serverside.
The only downside is quite tricky installation - https://github.com/learnboost/node-canvas/wiki

Answer (score 0):

What makes this tricky is that you need something that works both server side **and** client side.

If you are willing to limit yourself to SVG (which means you can kiss goodbye) to older versions of MSIE, then that can be constructed as per any DOM.